# PySide6 - Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" error

Tags: pyqt

After then I installed Pyside6(pip install pyside6), I couldn't use it cause of error message occur.

< Error Message >

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I tried changed path

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by add system path.

Path Name : QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH

Path Value : address of the file name : 'qwindows.dll'

Comment: Why is this needed? Why doesn't pip handle this?